# Define a consistent visual style that identifies mod-only information and controls

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools

As a mod, you can sometimes forget, or just don't even know what parts of the UI are displaying privileged, mod-only information. Checking things out with socks, or on other sites where you have 20k rep (at which point all non-mod UI features are unlocked) can be impractical.

A recent example is the stats that are visible on the election page to mods. There are no hints that this information is not public to everyone visiting the page.

A simple solution to this would be a simple style rule that is applied to *all* mod information. It needn't be much more complex than `border: 1px solid red`. This would make it completely unambiguous what is a mod tool and what isn't, particularly in lesser-used parts of the UI like elections. It would also help new mods find their feet much more quickly.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't want to accidentally reveal personally identifying information that is privy only to mods :|

Comment: @wont not necessarily PII, just any non-public info.

Comment: It's not that simple though, e.g. in the example you make, that's not PII, just "secret". OTOH I agree there's other stuff which *is* PII and is not marked as such.

Comment: @Sklivvz You could go further and differentiate between privileged information and sensitive information, but at the moment there's no distinction (visually) between either of those and public information.

Comment: The thing is, we already track access to PII, so it would be easier to identify and mark out. Sensitive information... not so much, not realistic. However I'm afraid (and I might be wrong) that marking PII in red, would give the message that the rest of sensitive information is disclosable. It isn't.

Comment: @Sklivvz This is exactly the issue, some kind of `class='mod-only'` to slap around all such stuff. I appreciate it's a big ask if such a distinction is not already made in the code.